# Can I answer a question without the fear of down vote?

Tags: support, answers, downvotes

Right now I have two cases:

1. I provided an answer and got a "nice" down vote with no obvious reason... The question was not "good", my answer was either not comprehensive but I provided a starting point for the author, something to start working.
2. I saw a question which it was a bit unclear. I wrote an answer that could handle the demand but it was not "elegant" so I deleted it. I was afraid that it will get a down vote.

So the million dollar question is:

Is there a way to give an answer without fear? I don't care if it gets points, I just want to be certain that it won't get a truck load of down votes.

I am sure that a lot will say that "bad" answer decrease the quality of the site but I have always found answers to my issues in the various "bad" answers.

Comment: A starting point is not an answer. Put it into a comment. Please [edit] your question and include links to the answers you talk about.

Comment: @LutzHorn is right. If it is unclear, you should ask in comment some details. You shouldn't be afraid of downvotes, everyone has a lot of them. You should feel either your answer is helpful or not. You would use your own answer for that question? If yes, just go right ahead and pay attention to the quality and upvotes will come for sure!

Comment: @LutzHorn i want to check something out first so i won't provide links right now..personally i think it is not needed.

Comment: Wow...edits from big players....too  bad they deleted the "gaming element" of my question

Comment: Be afraid! Be very afraid! It pushes you to write better content. ;)

Comment: @deceze or better write no content....and if some more follow the same philoshopy...no answers...great....back to the stone age....

Comment: You may have gotten the wrong message. :) SO is a very critical peer-reviewed environment. You're putting your code and professional knowledge in the face of many other professional programmers and are giving them carte blanche to publicly critique your work. **Use this as growing opportunity, don't shy away from it.**

Comment: No, that will not happen. Most answers I see are either worth an upvote or at least not downvote. I only downvote if an answer is plain wrong. But if you don't try to write good answers, perhaphs by comparing your answers to those that get upvotes, you will never learn. Just try.

Comment: Assuming [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30445771/519348) is the answer you are concerned about, the down-vote may simply be because you're "answering" a question that should be closed.

Comment: @TZHZ have you wondered what the author has to say about the question and the down vote...Are you certain 110% that the author has the "luxury" of accepting a down voting......

Comment: I *do* think there answer given below are leading somewhere. Please read them, they contain good advice.

Comment: We are trying to answer your question. If you are starting to make fun of the people who try to help you, SO might not be the best place for you.

Comment: My point wasn't that I was traumatized, dear John, but that your lack of basic care in your typing and lack of clarity in what you're saying is indicative of the problems you will have with this site. Your response to my first comment makes no sense. "luxury of accepting a down voting" -- what the hell does that mean?

Comment: @LutzHorn i don't like making fun but giving too much attention to single letter typo seems to me ....i can't find the right words...

Comment: @TZHX at first sorry for the comment..i tried to edit it but i couldn't......i am getting a lot for a single letter typo..anyway...are you sure you want to discuss with me about the "luxury" comment ? if so let me know

Comment: There are a lot of features here in SO that make the life of everybody easier. One is caring about the quality of answers, another is knowing the small hidden things like autocompleting usernames. Please accept our advise and our help.

Comment: OOps the first down vote....yes...

Comment: John: every single one of my comments has been on-topic here, none of your responses to me appear to be. You're the one obsessed with a typo, I made a mention of it as part of a wider context. You do not appear to be genuinely seeking input and help from the community, but -- at the moment -- are coming across as someone who just wants to whine about a single down-vote they received.

Comment: @TZHX just count the comments about the typo....

Comment: @TZHX I do think you're being a bit pushy here and are escalating for no real reason. Let's not keep poking based on a typo, whatever larger flaws you interpret into that one "mistake".

Comment: @deceze Thank you for your feedback.  I have been trying to steer the conversation in a productive direction -- the user still has not clarified what they mean by their first response to me. Can you explain it?

Comment: @TZHX You mean "luxury of downvote"? I'd guess that means "I already have virtually no rep to begin with" and/or "that gets me one step closer to a ban". Other users (\*cough\*) have to "worry" less about one downvote...

Comment: @TZHX ...well about the clarification you needed..some time ago i had a really big issue...i was searching for a solution all over the INTERNET and i couldn't find an answer....eventually i landed on SO...i made the question and...down vote chaos....the question was considered not "appropriate" ....so i wasted countless days to figure out a solution by my own ....and thankfully i did....but at the time i posted the question it was matter of life and death for me and i just wanted a helping hand....so lesson learned...never ask a question...go figure it by yourself....

Comment: @John Stackoverflow is not a life line. Sorry, you don't come here to get some urgent fix for your immediate problem. That's exactly what we're ***not*** here for. SO is for posting well thought out content and even maintaining and improving it over time.

Comment: @deceze ...i found it out the hard way... as i said ...never post an urgent question on SO....downvoters are lurking around...

Comment: To be clear: it's not the urgency that produces the downvotes. We simply want *good content of lasting value*. You could have a very urgent question, yet still post a good question that will get good answers and upvotes. But we do not want a ton of *"HELP URGENT WHY THIS CODEZ NO WORKZ?!"* content here, that's not what we're for. The problem is that "urgent" questions are often low quality; but you can change that by posting a good question, even if it's urgent.

Comment: Hope you'll take this all to heart and stick around and contribute good content in the future!

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly, **`Are you certain 110% that the author has the "luxury" of accepting a down voting?`** I'm afraid I don't care about the *author* when voting. They are entirely irrelevant. I care about the content. If the content is bad, but comes from a good friend, I would (and have) still down vote it. There is no need to "accept" a down vote, it is given to you freely. `i wasted countless days to figure out a solution by my own` -- that doesn't sound like a waste, that sounds like you learned something. good for you!

Comment: I guess the phrase "I don't care about the author when voting" sums up the SO philosophy....

Comment: Yes, it does. It can take a little getting used to, but it is at the core of what makes SO such a useful resource. Don't take anything personally on these sites and you'll have a much better time with them.

Comment: This I have to agree with. We're not personal, we're technical. We put accuracy and usefulness over personalities. You are not what you write, those are two separate things. Your reputation is indirectly accumulated by the quality of the content you write. A single downvote is not targeting you personally, it's pointing out problems in the content you wrote. (From here see my answer below...)

Answer (score 20):

Fear is a good thing. Stackoverflow is a very critical peer-reviewed environment. You're putting your code and professional knowledge in the face of many other professional programmers and are giving them carte blanche to publicly critique your work. **Use this as growing opportunity, don't shy away from it.** Push yourself to write the best possible content you can, to not leave an opening to be criticised. **Learn from critique**; it's not there to hurt you, it's there to point out *flaws* in your post. You can only eliminate flaws when you're aware of them. You can only get better by eliminating flaws. It helps *everyone*, the OP, future visitors, and not least of all you.

Comment: `Learn from critique` sometimes it is not easy to determine the actual reason a downvote is referring to exactly. Is it the writing style, is it the content proposed, is it the general opinion of the down-voter on a certain topic, ... It would be great if critique has to be explained in textual form to give the author some way to improve the post once peers have reviewed it. I could imagine some opt-in settings when selected a voter has to argument his decision anonymously (where other users can join or challenge this argumentation), similar to the former documentation project

Answer (score 9):

> Is there a way to give an answer without fear?

Yes there is, let go of the fear. You have to realise that the fear is something you produce yourself and has nothing to do with the down vote or your answer.

We want good questions and answers here, and that means you have first have to conform to, and align with, what the site's visitors deem good.

A down vote is just a down vote and somebody else's expression that the answer is "not useful" (the text you see when hovering the down arrow), and anonymous in addition to that. It doesn't mean **you** are down-voted, or that you are bad, just that the answer did not conform to what is considered to be a good answer.

Given the herd mentality of people, even a few down votes should not give you fear. If you get enough down votes and answer is flagged, the answer might even get deleted. Do you have to fear that as well? No, **learn from it** if there is something to learn (from comments, delete reasons, etc).

And if you honestly have no clue about what might have been wrong, come to meta and ask what you might have done wrong (as you did) and learn from the answers there.

You can answer by providing that answer, but make sure an answer is an answer (as defined on this site) and is useful and not e.g. chit-chat or full of distractions. An unclear question cannot be answered. Therefore an answer to such question can be useful, but most of the time it would be guesswork.
Make the OP improve the question, by posting comments with request for clarification (and please tell the OP to update their post, instead of commenting on your comments), and/or flag the post as unclear. Once the post is clear, and you know an answer just post it. Don't look back (too much, reviewing for typos, etc. is of course recommended).

Comment: Great first paragraph! :)

Comment: I like "Its not you who is being downvoted" too. That probably nails it for anyone experiencing this kind of invisible peer pressure.

Comment: `you have first have to conform to, and align with, what the site's visitors deem good` so basically if the whole Internet uses certain terms incorrectly (like `REST` i.e.) one has to write answers that apply to this misconception or otherwise face constant downvotes of people looking for validations of their beliefes?

Answer (score 2):

Everything necessary is written down in the Help Center: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

First, you should realize that the vote usually isn't against you as a person, it's simply an indication of the strength of what you wrote. It's not a *penalty*, it's an *indicator*

Here's how I suggest being able to post without fear of the down-vote: use your full name for your account, and make sure your profile makes it possible to know who you are. People should be able to search for you on the internet, and find links to your answers through that search.

When you know that your work can be tied back to you personally and you are not relying on anonymity, it makes you write better answers. It causes you to think "am I really making a positive contribution?" each time you post something.  Ask yourself "do I want my mentor / mentee / partner / co-worker / future employer to know I wrote this?".

If you aren't writing something you're proud of, don't post an answer. Be proud of what you write, and the chance of it being down-voted goes down. Unfortunately, the chance will never reach zero because there are spiteful people out there. I've had some very good answers down-voted. More often then not, however, when I get a down-vote it's because I wrote an answer that wasn't very useful.

Comment: I got downvoted by someone with 47.5K rep because I did not answer "the specific question", but rather I realized that trying to "help" the person with the "solution" was what they were really after. I deleted my answer, left a comment to the OP that I could not help them. They reworded the question and confirmed in fact that I was right and to please continue to help. I felt targeted, lost interest for a short time in contributing to SO, and questioned if my investments here were worth it. Well, they are; not for the OP, but for the others who benefit from my answers whether they vote or not.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be misunderstanding  a few things:

- So is a site where you publicize your work and content into the open, to be peer reviewed by an array of experienced programmers and other professionals. So the opportunity of getting criticized heavily for shoddy work is something you always need to be aware of.
- Downvotes are strictly not personal insults and should never be seen as such. They are tools for the community to detect worthy and well-researched answers and avoid shoddy ones. They are also indicators for the person recieving them that their work was not up to standard.
- Stack Overflow is a learning opportunity for the Answerers as much as for the Askers. Don't be afraid of getting downvotes, instead, use them as an opportunity to hone your skills in programming and to fix any eventual shortfalls your code has.