# How do I contribute to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, new-users

*Disclaimer: This is not "being a new user sucks, plz give more points!"*

I've come upon an issue with using Stack Overflow: It's hard to contribute.

That comes in a variety of literal and figurative forms, especially for a new user.

- Which questions are worth answering? I know there's a post about "bad" questions, but should I try to answer them anyway?
- It's really shitty-feeling when you provide an answer, only to have the OP never return to appreciate you (and give you rep! Which leads into...).
- The reputation points system, to me, feels over-constrained. I'm sure that's because I haven't had to witness all the atrocities committed over the years, but still. If I have a comment or question about a question, my only choices are to write an answer or wait to find out.

  - If I wait to find out, then someone with the proper reputation points can come in and ask, then post the answer, and then my existence is superfluous.
- With all the users online, how do I contribute the one gleaming pearl of my knowledge in a vast treasury of veteran (workplace and to this site) gems?

The closest questions I found were: [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295242/can-i-answer-a-question-without-the-fear-of-down-vote/308495#308495) about downvotes and [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow) about "being a new contributor".

Meta meta question: Does this question contribute anything?

Comment: The only motivation that *really* works is recognizing that contributing answers makes you a better programmer.  If you don't get that feeling then you are probably answering the wrong kind of questions.  Skip the "easy" ones, dig into a hard one.

Comment: @HansPassant I'd say that compared to many other humans, I'm fairly altruistic (note: the lack of the words "humble"), but I love me some words of affirmation. Probably because I have a lot of self doubt, but a "good job" goes  **LOOONGGG** way in making me feel like, well, I did a "good" job.

Comment: Hmya, that is the kind of altruism that so often gets disappointed by an OP that doesn't give a hoot.  There just isn't much point to it, spending your free time is supposed to be a fun.  If you call it "looking for affirmation from peers" then you'd get closer I suppose.

Comment: @HansPassant, can't discern "HMYA". I do enjoy the helping part and the learning part, don't get me wrong. But the site specifically puts in the "back-patting" mechanic, so I want to benefit from it. On sites without rep? I don't care about the recognition as much.

Comment: [My answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/304227/4320665) to a very related question (with a more critical tone): [Why is contributing on StackOverflow impossible?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304223/why-is-contributing-on-stackoverflow-impossible)

Comment: given your spelling, grammar and formatting, starting with [meta-tag:edits] looks like a safe bet for you. Pick posts from your favorite tag and bring them to better shape. This way you'll better learn how system works and how to write your own questions and answers. Not to mention that this will increase your reputation - approved [meta-tag:suggested-edits] bring +2 to editor

Comment: Posting a decent question on meta about getting rep is a nice way to get easy rep apparently :-)

Comment: @PeeHaa _Yes, yes, my evil plan is coming together_ er... I mean, um.... Who knew?! haha ...

Comment: @gnat cool! Great tip! I was also surprised to learn that I gained 40 rep today... so there's that. I'll try to start cataloging my favorites; I already have my feed highlighting my favorite tags.

Comment: wrt editing, you can learn how to do it properly from [this edits history](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/591/peter-mortensen?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). Click the links "approved edit" and check what is changed and what is _kept as is_, edit summaries etc. This user is top editor at Stack Overflow, I picked account on other site where he has less reputation so that his edits pass through review, just like your will pass here

Comment: My tip... stay away from high traffic tags.. find a nice low traffic tag.. start answering and you will learn both how to answer and more about the subject.... low-traffic no hurry (FGITW) you have time to study and post a good answer... not a lot of rep  but who gives, let your answer stand in time...

Comment: "I've come upon an issue with using Stack Overflow: It's hard to contribute."  Question.  **What in life are you *really good at* ?**  What's your expertise?

Comment: Look at SO as a source of programming exercises and puzzles. Find questions that interest you, and that require some research and/or coding effort to answer. Then, even if the OP never shows up again, at least you'll have learnt something, and you'll have the satisfaction of having solved a difficult/interesting problem.

Comment: sometimes answers wont give you rep immediately, they are more of an investment if its a good answer, over the years people will find your answer and upvote it

Comment: Thanks for all the great comments. I feel much less discouraged.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

> Which questions are worth answering? I know there's a post about "bad" questions, but should I try to answer them anyway?

No, you shouldn't try to answer bad questions.  You should either work to improve those questions so that they become good questions, or move on.  Bad questions are bad because they attract bad answers (or are fundamentally unanswerable).

> It's really shitty-feeling when you provide an answer, only to have the OP never return to appreciate you (and give you rep! Which leads into...)

This you just need to learn to not focus on.  You should be worried about the worldwide community at large, not just one person.  If the community as a whole feels that the answer is worthwhile, then the recognition of just one of the world's 7 billion+ inhabitants shouldn't be overly concerning.  If the general community consensus is that your answer is poor, then you should be very worried, even if the one person that asked the question liked it.

> The Rep System, to me feels over-constrained. I'm sure that's because I haven't had to witness all the atrocities committed over the years, but still. I have a comment or question about a Question, my only choices are to write an Answer or wait to find out

It takes between one and two decent posts to be able to comment.  That's not really that hard.  Finding one or two questions that are *already* good questions for you to answer, before moving on to trying to help an author turn a bad question into a good question, is really a step you should take.  Once you've started to get a hand for how to answer a question that is *already good*, (which should probably take you longer than it will take to get 50 rep) *then* consider spending time holding the hand of question authors while they work to improve an unanswerable question.

> If I wait to find out, then someone with the proper rep can come in and ask, then post the answer and then my existence is superfluous.

If someone else asks a clarifying question, or otherwise helps the OP improve their question, you can still use the information the OP responds with to answer.

That said, if you're finding that you *are* superfluous, then you should be finding ways to make yourself not superfluous.  If you're only ever doing things that lots of other people can and will do, then you're not adding value.  Find questions that are good, and that others can't (or at least haven't) answered and answer them.  Learn what you need to learn to *make* yourself valuable, rather than opining the fact that you're not.

> With all the users online, how do I contribute the one gleaming pearl of my knowledge in a vast treasury of veteran (workplace and to this site) gems?

Spend some time thinking about what types of problems you can solve better than other people, and search for questions about that topic, or find a topic that other people struggle to deal with, and learn what you need to learn to be able to answer them.

Comment: Great answer! I think this qualifies as "THE" answer. Is the general answering convention the same in Meta as in standard Stack Overflow?

Comment: man were you right about that 50 rep thing.... that escalated quickly. I had two good answers and this question and that skyrocketed me into comment-ville.

Comment: @goodguy5 You don't get rep for meta posts.  You earned nothing for posting this question.

Comment: oh, but I did. I got visibility. I'm fairly certain that the reason my other posts got attention, was because people found them from this question. I may not have received rep, but I did get _something_... oh! And a badge for +10 on a post :)

Comment: @TechnikEmpire, (and Servy), Nah, it's like like that. It is exactly as I described it: I want to help and I wasn't sure how to feel like I was helping. There have been a lot of great posts on the topic and I am content.

Comment: "It takes between one and two decent posts to be able to comment. That's not really that hard." Gotta disagree with that. As a beginner, interpreting posts -- both questions and answers -- without commenting for clarification is tough because you haven't learned the assumed context. The point where comments are most useful is when you don't have access to them.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire don't you think saying "There's only so many questions you can ask.." is a bit like Bill Gates saying (or not) "640k should be enough for anybody"?

Comment: Technology is constantly evolving, and it's a mistake to think it will stay as it is now. There are new programming languages, new tools, etc... So there will always be new questions that can be asked, including questions that will accumulate many votes over time.

Comment: @Servy This answer doesn't satisfy me. The reason is because it's lacking the cases where both the OP and "the community" - in this case a community familiar with SO but not necessarily knowledgeable in the particular field - are biased or unreasonable. Celebrities' answers have a much higher chance of getting upvote while new users' are welcomed with a look of doubt. Furthermore, when you are shunned by the community, you are given no chance to correct or explain yourself. Your answer or comment is removed outright and it gives a real shitty feeling of being shut off and kick out the door.

Comment: To explain my point, please look at this recent answer of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35935723/css-link-hover-not-for-images/35935935#35935935 To sum it up, in this answer, I made the mistake of answering for the asker, but not for the crowd. Other people - without the knowledge that my answer should be used in the context of the OP's website - followed the lead of the first downvoter and my answer is soon removed. The OP who later couldn't find my answer went on to accept another that's a reverse of mine, while commenting that he prefer my solution. I had no chance to explain.

Comment: @AVAVT People don't upvote the answers of the top contributors because they're a top contributor.  Their answers get upvotes because they've spent a lot of time and effort learning how to post good answers, so they post good answers, and get upvotes as a result.  People that haven't spent the time to learn how to post answers tend to not post good answers, and the votes reflect that quality.  Your answer wasn't downvoted because you're new, it's downvoted because it's not a good answer.

Answer (score 36):

Pick a tag you have expertise in. Go to the "unanswered" view, and scroll through until you find something you know the answer to. Give it. Lather, rinse, repeat. Occasionally you'll find something you *almost* know the answer to, and it'll bug you as much as the person asking it. That's where you learn the most. Investigate, report, answer. You won't necessarily pick up much rep that way typically, but don't think of doing it for the rep, think of doing it because questions should have answers, and because it gives you a workout, and you learn a little each time.

Comment: Yeah, some of the most satisfying answers to me were those where I had to do a lot of research, learned a lot, and then received a tiny amount of reputation for it.

Answer (score 11):

I know this is kind of the obvious answer, but I think the best thing new users can do is ask good questions and provide good answers in their areas of expertise. If you do that, your rep will quickly rise high enough to access the restricted functionality on SO. I know it is discouraging to ask or answer and not get any responses or reputation from it, but you will find that as you ask and answer you will occasionally hit a really good topic and you will get a lot of good response and will be rewarded.

Disclaimer of my own, I am not a high rep user, but even at just a few hundred rep I now have access to most of the things I would like to do and I don't feel as restricted as when I was sub 100 rep, so don't think you have to wait until you have thousands of rep before you can really contribute

Answer (score 5):

I agree with all others answer, just some of my thinking and experience.

**Don't focus on SO reputation** - that's the main point, yeah it may be hard especially when you have worked on an answer for some time and the poster comments *'thank you sir!!!'* and that's all, you never see him again and ocasionally even if he accepts the answer you can see after some time *'user deleted'* info in your reputation. That's not worth it, your time, and probably nerves. That's the bad point of this reputation system (I think I remember I read some discussion about it somewhere), but to be honest I can't imagine better system to differentiate users who are good contributors and those 'bad' ones.

SO is really great place and community if you think about it in little different manner. If you are interested in programming, then there is a very big chance that you will find help for your problems. The second main thing is that it's a great place to learn new thigs, either by reading answer and problems or trying to find the answer. If you try to solve the problem that it's also not so obvius for you, then even if somebody answers the problem before you do, you always gain experience - and in this case you are always a winner.

If you are really interested in gaining reputation some hints from my side - I've also 'started' in those *worse times for reputation harvesting*, where all simple answers are already answered with 1k votes up, you find another person that has bigger number beside his image and additional *'k'* letter. So here they are:

- don't answer bad question, I know it's already mentioned, but it's really important. It will take some of your time, and there is a very big chance that question will be closed/deleted and after that your reputation is retracted,
- it may be hard to answer at most popular tags like [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and so on - they are thousands of programmers and the 'easy' questions get few answers in few minutes. It's easier to answer questions to that tags at weekends - most of regular programmers take a break, so there are less people 'participating' the race.
- you may try to focus on questions from unanswered queue, but try to pick those from users who already have some reputation (lets say more than 49). Also as you hunt for reputation, take a look if user is active - you will find 'last seen' in profile. If the user has been last seen few years ago, then there is big chance that you won't get reputation from him. Of course you can get reputation from otheres, but if question is low on views, then the chance is small. Of course after answering each question that required some research from you, you become a better programmer.

Answer (score 4):

My major reason for being here, and "contributing" is because I find problem solving interesting.

I also recognise that practise is the route to mastery - and stackoverflow gives me more scenarios and opportunities.

Fortunately this process is also a good fit for the site ideals.  I contribute as a result.

Don't get too worried about feeling you *should* do things. Nothing here is mandatory.  Just do what you find interesting. And honestly, if that is "something that isn't Stack Overflow"...  Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

Everything about SO would be great if it ***wasn't for the people asking questions***.

The only reason to answer questions ... I mean in life generally, or SO ... is that by explaining something to someone else, ***YOU get better***.

That's why you go around explaining things.

The fact that to do this, you have to deal with clowns asking silly questions, is a real pain.

There's an old joke in say the advertising industry... "Everything about the ad business would be fantastic, if it wasn't for the damned clients!" Same deal here.

If you're asking here about ' gaining! "points"! ' on this site. They're a joke. I just try to give all mine away by abusing the absurd bounty system.

The simple riposte is: get a life.  Or Get.A.Life .. whatever the trendy punctuation is these days.  i.e., go out on *more* dates, have *more* sex, *more* children, and drink *more* whisky while doing *more* work.

Simple fact: every single person here today will be stone dead quite soon. While you're young, enjoy yourself and answer some questions. So you can get *better* at something while you're still young enough.